Is it possible to change the artboard's selection outline indicator color?
Selecting an artboard puts a thin black outline on around it. I was wondering if there's a way I could change its thickness and/or color to a more contrasted one. I have impaired vision--although I can see where it is, it takes a while for me to notice.

I don't think there's anything more than what one sees in Preferences > Interface
But you could always create a workaround.

Create a new layer
Draw a rectangle the same size as your artboard.
Center the rectangle to the artboard both vertically and horizontally
Add whatever stroke weight/color you want to this rectangle.
With the layer highlighted in the Layers Panel, choose Options for "Layer [x]" from the Layer Panel Menu
Untick Print and tick Lock in the options dialog and click OK

You then have a custom artboard border that won't print or export and is just a visual indicator. Because its also locked, you can't select it by mistake either.
You can move this layer up or down in the layer stack to show this custom artboard border any time, it it happens to get covered by other objects.
This seems like a lot, but if you do this a couple times it gets rather quick. And you can create an action to accomplish all this as well, so it could just be a simple shortcut.

Another option is to place Guides at the artboard edges. You can change the color of guides in Preferences > Guides & Grid, but it's not possible to change the stroke weight of guides.

You can also draw the rectangle in the first part and then make that rectangle a Guide (View > Guides > Make Guides) to match your guide coloring preferences.
